# Background Fixed Bug when use Google Maps in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser

I have a an element that receives an image of background with fixed values ​​and cover, and I 'm using Google Maps too, but when I use Google Maps on chorme with this element , it seems that Google Maps cancels the fixed value of the element , what it can be?

The CSS of Background IMage Fixed:

```
.destaque {background-size: cover; background-color: #333; background-attachment: fixed; z-index: 2; position: relative;}
```

The Google Maps API:

```
<script>
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });
}
```

In TAg:

```
<section id="map"></section>
```